# Matrix with different element distribution in R

Tags: r, matrix, random, distribution

I would like to create a matrix `M`:

```
n <- 10
prob0 <- 0.75
M <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), size=n*n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(prob0, 1 - prob0)), n, n)
```

where, for each `(i, j)` element, `prob0` is drawn from `uniform([0,1])` without recurring to a for loop (if it is possible). The general problem of which my issue is a specialization is: is there a way to create in R a matrix, say `NxN`, in which each element comes from a different distribution without recurring to a for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want a matrix `M` in which each element `(i,j)` will be 0 if a random value `r`, drawn from a `uniform([0,1])`, is higher than `p` and 1 otherwise.  This can be easily achieved with:

```
n <- 10
prob0 <- 0.75
matrix(runif(n * n) > prob0, n, n)
```

If you want a different `prob0` for each item, just replace it with `runif(n * n)` as well:

```
matrix(runif(n * n) > runif(n * n), n, n)
```

But at this point, you are simply comparing pairs of randoms, so

```
matrix(runif(n * n) > 0.5, n, n)
```

yields the same result.

If you want completely different distributions for each item on the matrix you can do something like creating two lists, one with the names of the functions and another with their parameters, and use `mapply` + `do.call`:

```
n_ <- 10
dists <- list(
  NORM_11 = "rnorm",
  UNIF = "runif",
  NORM_23 = "rnorm")
params <- list(
  NORM_11 = list(n = n_, mean = 1, sd = 1),
  UNIF = list(n = n_),
  NORM_23 = list(n = n_, mean = 2, sd = 3))
mapply(dists, params, FUN = do.call)
```

Note that the names (`NORM_11`, etc) are merely for convenience, and `mapply` matches `dists` and `params` by position, so make sure both lists match.

In this example you get 10 randoms from each distribution, aggregated by columns (naming the `dists` list helps, as the result's columns will have the same names).  If you want something like a 10x10 matrix sampled from 100 different distributions I suggest you find some way to generate the `dists` and `parameters` and set `n_ <- 1`. This will give you a numeric vector with 100 items, which you can then easily shape into a matrix either using `matrix()` or by setting the `dims()`.

If you want to always use the same distribution but change parameters, the method above becomes much simpler:

```
mapply(mean = 101:200, sd = 1:101, FUN = rnorm, MoreArgs = list(n = 1))
```

(I still can't see the point of taking only one sample from a random distribution... but I guess that's off-topic)

Comment: Ok, and if i would like to create, say, a matrix with each entry with a different law, e.g. (1,1) Normal{mean 0, sd 1}, (1,2) uniform{[0,1]}, (1,3) Normal{mean 2, sd 3} without a loop?